# Set custom x, y position of nodes and their children in d3 tree diagram

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, hierarchy

I have d3 tree structure requirement. This one.

[image]

Two things to understand from the above picture:

1. **Headers** will have multiple parents(**wells**).
2. I must be able to drag and drop **links** that connect **wells** to **headers** to other headers.

I have implemented this functionality by adding both **wells** and **headers** as children to **fields**. I have given additional **depth** to nodes that are headers so that they are not in the same line as wells. To add multiple parents to headers i'm using a method to generate links and passing the source and target nodes to that method, to generate the multiple parent links. Like so.[image]

As you can see, the depth has been set for **RK Battery**, but since it a child of **RK Field**, it's x and y position are being set relative to the position of the wells under RK Field. I want to set custom positions for the batteries and it's children should be able to take the x and y position relative to it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, simply by assigning the values. You can split the a `d3.tree` visualization into 2 parts for understanding:

- Layout
- Rendering

The first part is the actual functionality you're gaining by using `d3.tree`, it's calculating the layout of all the nodes for you and assigning an `x` and `y` position to each. You can see this mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#_tree).

The second part of the visualization is the rendering, where you take all the nodes that have been laid out and you draw them on screen using the given positions. Before starting this part you can manually move a node anywhere you want:

```
// Run the layout
d3.tree(rootNode);

// Example of moving a node
rootNode.children[0].x += 10;
rootNode.children[0].y += 10;
```

Because your link data should look like this, where the actual data node itself represents the source and target it means moving either the source or target should also cause the link to render to the correct new location.

```
const links = [
    { source: {...}, target: {...} },
];
```

Comment: `rootNode.children[0].x += 10;
rootNode.children[0].y += 10;`

if i use this it will set x and y position only for the immediate children of the root node right?

Comment: @RoopeshKumarRamesh no, that will set the position just for that single node. The children will be un-affected.

Comment: @Ian : I gave this a try but I still see the nodes in the x and  y axis that the d3 has computed. Any reasons?